# My chat user profile links to Meta instead of the main site

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, profile-page, chat

So, this has been an on-again off-again oddity in chat. My profile, unlike others' profiles, links to meta as a base profile.

[image: The offending profile]

As you can see from rene's, this is not normal.

[image: A normal profile.]

I've tried to change it directly, but whenever I edit my chat profile, I end up editing my overarching Stack Exchange profile or hitting my [Stack Overflow Chat profile](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/2958086/compass) which lists my parent user as a Meta account instead of my main account.

Something went horribly wrong. In terms of how serious it is, it doesn't affect my Chat experience at all, so fixing it is definitely not a priority, but for sanity purposes I am just going to go ahead and report this.

Comment: Are you saying rene is normal?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, I've fixed it for you. It only seems to affect 11 users (including you) - I'll see what  I can find out about the original cause.

Comment: Yep Affects me too :(